# Scraping a forum: cannot scrape posts that have a table within them

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've almost finished writing my first scraper!

I've run into a snag, however: I can't seem to grab the contents of posts that contain a table (posts that cite another post, in other words).

This is the code that extracts post contents from the soup object. It works just fine:

```
    def getPost_contents(soup0bj):

        try:
          soup0bj = (soup0bj)
          post_contents = []

          for content in soup0bj.findAll('', {'class' : 'post_content'}, recursive = 'True'):
             post_contents.append(content.text.strip())

         ...#Error management

         return (post_contents)
```

Here's an example of what I need to scrape (highlighted in yellow):

[Problem post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6eVX.jpg)

(URL, just in case: http://forum.doctissimo.fr/sante/diabete/savoir-diabetique-sujet_170840_1.htm#t657906)

How do I get the contents that I've highlighted? And why does my current getPostcontents function not work in this particular instance? As far as I can see, the strings are still under div class=post_contents.

EDIT EDIT EDIT

This is how I am getting my BeautifulSoup:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

    def getHTMLsoup(url):

       try:
          html = urlopen(url)
       ...#Error management

       try:
          soup0bj = Soup(html.read().decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
          time.sleep(5)
       ...#Error management

       return (soup0bj)
```

EDIT2 EDIT2 EDIT2

These are the relevant bits of the scraper: (Sorry about the dump!)

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
    from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve
    from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError
    import time, re

    def getHTMLsoup(url):


       try:
          html = urlopen(url)

       except HTTPError as e:
          return None
          print('The server hosting{} is unavailable.'.format(url), '\n')
          print('Trying again in 10 minutes...','\n')
          time.sleep(600)
          getHTMLsoup(url)

       except URLError as e:
          return None 
          print('The webpage found at {} is unavailable.'.format(url),'\n')
          print('Trying again in 10 minutes...','\n')
          time.sleep(600)
          getHTMLsoup(url)

        try:
            soup0bj = Soup(html.read().decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
            time.sleep(5)

        except AttributeError as e:
          return None
          print("Ooops, {}'s HTML structure wasn't detected.".format(url),'\n')


        return soup0bj

    def getMessagetable(soup0bj):
       try:
          soup0bj = (soup0bj)
          messagetable = []

          for data in soup0bj.findAll('tr', {'class' : re.compile('message.*')}, recursive = 'True'):

       except AttributeError as e:
          print(' ')

       return (messagetable)

    def getTime_stamps(soup0bj):

       try:
          soup0bj = (soup0bj)
          time_stamps = []

          for stamp in soup0bj.findAll('span', {'class' : 'topic_posted'}):
        time_stamps.append(re.search('..\/..\/20..', stamp.text).group(0))

       except AttributeError as e:
          print('No time-stamps found. Moving on.','\n')

       return (time_stamps)

    def getHandles(soup0bj):

       try:
          soup0bj = (soup0bj)
          handles = []

          for handle in soup0bj.findAll('span', {'data-id_user' : re.compile('.*')}, limit = 1):
             handles.append(handle.text)

        except AttributeError as e:
           print("")

        return (handles)

    def getPost_contents(soup0bj):

       try:
          soup0bj = (soup0bj)
          post_contents = []

          for content in soup0bj.findAll('div', {'class' : 'post_content'}, recursive = 'True'):
             post_contents.append(content.text.strip())

       except AttributeError as e:
          print('Ooops, something has gone wrong!')

       return (post_contents)


    html = ('http://forum.doctissimo.fr/sante/diabete/savoir-diabetique-sujet_170840_1.htm')

    for soup in getHTMLsoup(html):
       for messagetable in getMessagetable(soup):

          print(getTime_stamps(messagetable),'\n')
          print(getHandles(messagetable),'\n')
          print(getPost_contents(messagetable),'\n')
```

Comment: What is your current output? I see this post extracted as well as others.

Comment: Works for me too, although it is stuck to the previous text

Comment: Hey, thanks for asking! At the moment, it outputs all posts, save those that have a have a table in div class=post_contents

Comment: What might my problem be? Any guesses?

Comment: @Gabriel, what version of Beautifulsoup and how are you getting the html?

Comment: Thanks, Padraic. I'm reaflly baffled, guys. I really, really, do not have this post. Is there possibly something wrong with my soup object?

Comment: Even using `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` does not break it for me so I have no idea, I also tried all parsers, add your exact code and versions of all packages you are using

Comment: Why are you using `.decode('utf-8', 'replace')`?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.0 and Bs4 0.01. How much of my code should I put up?

Comment: The site is in French --if I don't specify utf-8, all the latin characters are garbled. Should I do something different?

Comment: You tried passing the bytes  directly to bs4?

Comment: Hang on, I'm a linguistics grad. :P How do I do that?

Comment: I thought I had the solution but there is something else going on, it is 100 percent encoding I just have to figure out exactly what us happening, I will edit my answer in a sec

Comment: @Gabriel, try using  `urlopen(r).read().decode("latin-1")`  and tell me your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your decoding, it is not utf-8, if you remove the `"replace"` your code will error with:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 253835: invalid continuation byte
```

The data seems to  be *latin-1* encoded, decoding to *latin-1* causes no errors but the output does look off in certain parts, using.

```
 html  = urlopen(r).read().decode("latin-1")
```

will work but as I mentioned, you get weird output like:

```
"diabĂ¨te en cas d'accident de la route ou malaise isolĂŠ ou autre ???"
```

Another option would be to pass an accept-charset header:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
headers = {"accept-charset":"utf-8"}
r = Request("http://forum.doctissimo.fr/sante/diabete/savoir-diabetique-sujet_170840_1.htm#t657906",headers=headers)
html  =  urlopen(r).read()
```

I get the exact same encoding issue using requests letting it handle the encoding, it is like the data has mixed encoding, some utf-8 and some latin-1. The headers returned from requests show the content-encoding as gzip as :

```
 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'
```

if we specify we want gzip and decode:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
headers = {"Accept-Encoding":"gzip"}
r = Request("http://forum.doctissimo.fr/sante/diabete/savoir-diabetique-sujet_170840_1.htm#t657906",headers=headers)
r = urlopen(r)

import gzip
gzipFile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=r)

print(gzipFile.read().decode("latin-1"))
```

We get the same errors with utf-8 and the same weird output decoding to latin-1. Interestingly in python2 both requests and urllib both work fine.

Using chardet:

```
r = urlopen(r)
import chardet
print(chardet.detect(r.read()))
```

reckons with around 71 percent confidence that it is `ISO-8859-2` but that again gives the same bad output.

```
{'confidence': 0.711104254322944, 'encoding': 'ISO-8859-2'}
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you just clarify where 'headers' and urlopen(r).read() go in my code? I'm not (yet) familiar with this way of doing things.

Comment: @Gabriel,  just use them as I have in the answer.

Comment: @Gabriel, no worries,do you see the weird output also?

Comment: Yeah, it was only when I was asking it to encode as utf-8 that I didn't get that. Wonder if being in different areas has something to do with it.

Comment: @Gabriel,  the only reason you did not see it decoding to utf-8 with replace was probably because you lost it, are you seeing output like diabĂ¨te?

Comment: Yeah, I am. But at least I get the missing posts now! I'll do some character converting once my scrape is done.